# Clojure test: global fixtures

Tags: testing, clojure

I've got some fixtures that boot up and close the database in my project.

Now it looks something like this:

```
(use-fixtures :once with-embedded-db)
```

while in the fixture itself I've got a dynamic variable that I use in different places:

```
(def ^:dynamic *db*)

(defn with-embedded-db [f]
  (binding [*db* (db/connect args)]
    (f)
    (finally
      (db/clean-up *db)))
```

Now, assume that `db/connect` and `db/clean-up` take some time.

**PROBLEM**:

When I run tests using `lein test`, it takes very long time, unnecessarily spending time on connecting and disconnecting to the db for every namespace.

**QUESTION**:

Is there a way to set up *global fixtures* so that when I run `lein test`, it calls it only **once for all the test namespaces**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have been better if that feature was added to leiningen itself. At least a ticket should be opened, if not a PR.

The following solution is dirty, but you can get the idea and transform it into something more intelligent.

```
;; profect.clj
:profiles 
 {:dev {:dependencies [[robert/hooke "1.1.2"]]

 :injections   [(require '[robert.hooke :as hooke])
  (defn run-all-test-hook [f & nss]
  (doall (map (fn [a]
   (when (intern a '*db*)
    (intern a '*db* "1234"))) nss))
  (apply f nss))
  (hooke/add-hook #'clojure.test/run-tests #'run-all-test-hook)
 ]}}
```

Note: leiningen itself uses robert/hooke in its core.
And then somewhere in tests:

```
(ns reagenttest.cli
    (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]))

(def ^:dynamic *db*) ;; should be defined in every NS where it is needed

(deftest Again
    (testing "new"
        (prn *db*)))
```

Comment: oh I'll definitely check this out! :) I tried to write the plugin, I thought of using `robert/hooke` as well, this looks like it makes sense... I'll let you know if it worked

Comment: I ended up using something similar to your code, big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [circleci.test](https://github.com/circleci/circleci.test), it supports [:global-fixtures](https://github.com/circleci/circleci.test#global-fixtures):

> ... you can define global fixtures that are only run once for the entire test run, no matter how many namespaces you run.